# Surface tension between water (liquid) methane (gas)

Tags: surface-tension, molecular-dynamics

In my project I should calculate surface tension between water and methane with lammps.

I write the program.I use SPC model for water and $l_j$ for methane and water - methane. But now I don't know how I calculate the surface tension.

Is it right I find $P_{xx}$, $P_{yy}$ and $P_{zz}$ , then finally using the equation $(P_{yy}+P_{zz})/2 - P_{xx}$?

Would appreciate comments on this.

Comment: This might help: http://boiling.seas.ucla.edu/boiling/Publications/S_Sinha.pdf